# Access to Sharepoint DB

Tags: content-database

I have installed SharePoint Foundation 2010 Foundation in Single mode. At installation a local db service was created at .\sharepoint and I haven't got permission on the databases to create a database dump from them.

How can I get permission to this database? I have local admin permission on this server.

Comment: This link should help you http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx, you just need to give yourself "owner" permission on that database.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 uses SQL Server Express edition as database server and you can connect to it using [SQL Server Express Manage Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7593). Connect to database using your admin account or the service account you had provided.
Also refer to this blog post: http://weblogs.asp.net/jevgeni/archive/2010/01/14/connecting-to-sharepoint-foundation-2010-internal-database.aspx

Comment: I know how I can connect to  SQL Server Express, and I can do that. But if I try to do something with WSS_Content (show all table for example) in SQL Managment Studio  I get  exception. I think at installation SharePoint create db with SQL Server authorization as well